# Redirect to special subdirectory if url contains a special word

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

There see a lot of instructions about rewrite in .htaccess, I know the following instructions in .htaccess would create a redirection

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)foobar(.*)$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

And

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} foobar
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [L,R]
```

But I don't really understand all /<*  stuff..
And i haven't seen any instructions how to send them to a url containing the original requested one..

Basicly I want to redirect any url that contains **/foobar/** or **/foobar** only, not if it's **/foobarone/** or **/testfoobar** ..

And I want it to be rewritten to *example.com/404/(the path they wrote)*

So accessing **example.com/comments/foobar** (with or without the ending slash)  it would be redirected to **example.com/404/comments/foobar**

That way it would trigger a 404 and also log the event, including the path they tried to access..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this rule as your topmost rule for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/404/
RewriteRule (?:^|/)foobar(?:/|$) /404%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: @anubhava is that case insensitive?

Comment: Yes it is due to use `NC` flag. Did it work for you?

Comment: I might add, even thou you answered my question right, it's not working the way I thought, since it becomes a loop..

Comment: Yes you're right. I realized and fixed it. Please try it after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Sorry it took a while, yes it works, I just got stuck on an plug-in I had that was suppose to do the same stuff (which I now have uninstalled) but apparently it still has some coding left, but I can't find it.  Your code works great, thx a lot!